# java.lang.ClassCastException in weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, weblogic, classcastexception

I am getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException` in Weblogic 10.3 when I am trying to set my values into session. Here's the full exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: model.common.SessionCheckBean cannot be cast to model.common.SessionCheckBean
```

Comment: Without any code this error message is close to useless.